# Ordenar filas en tabla PrettyTable

Tags: python

Este es el código:

```
from prettytable import PrettyTable


def agregar_equipos(table, cantidad):
    equipos_nuevos = []
    for _ in range(cantidad):
        equipo = {}
        equipo["nombre"] = input("Ingrese el nombre del equipo: ")
        equipo["puntos"] = int(input("Ingrese los puntos del equipo: "))
        equipo["dif_gol"] = int(input("Ingrese la diferencia de goles del equipo: "))
        equipos_nuevos.append(equipo)

    equipos_nuevos.sort(key=lambda x: (x["puntos"], x["dif_gol"]), reverse=True)

    posicion_inicial = table.rowcount + 1

    for posicion, equipo in enumerate(equipos_nuevos, start=posicion_inicial):
        table.add_row([posicion, equipo["nombre"], equipo["puntos"], equipo["dif_gol"]])

    print("Equipos agregados con éxito.")
    return table


def modificar_equipo(table):
    posicion = int(input("Ingrese la posición del equipo que desea modificar: "))
    puntos = int(input("Ingrese los nuevos puntos del equipo: "))
    dif_gol = int(input("Ingrese la nueva diferencia de goles del equipo: "))

    # Actualizar los datos del equipo en la tabla
    table._rows[posicion - 1][2] = puntos
    table._rows[posicion - 1][3] = dif_gol

    print("Equipo modificado con éxito.")


def main():
    table = PrettyTable()
    table.field_names = ["Posicion", "Equipo", "Puntos", "Dif_Gol"]

    while True:
        print("--- Menu ---")
        print("1. Modificar datos de un equipo")
        print("2. Agregar equipos")
        print("3. Mostrar tabla")
        print("4. Salir")

        opcion = input("Seleccione una opción: ")

        if opcion == "1":
            modificar_equipo(table)
        elif opcion == "2":
            cantidad_equipos = int(input("Ingrese la cantidad de equipos que desea agregar: "))
            table = agregar_equipos(table, cantidad_equipos)
        elif opcion == "3":
            table.sortby = "Posicion"
            table.reversesort = False
            print("Tabla actualizada:")
            print(table)
        elif opcion == "4":
            break
        else:
            print("Opción inválida. Por favor, seleccione una opción válida.")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

La tabla primero está así:

| Posicion | Equipo | Puntos | Dif_Gol |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | RIVER | 6 | 5 |
| 2 | BOCA | 6 | 4 |

Pero al modificar un equipo queda así y debería quedar Boca en el primer puesto.
Tabla actualizada:

| Posicion | Equipo | Puntos | Dif_Gol |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | RIVER | 6 | 5 |
| 2 | BOCA | 9 | 6 |

Answer (score 1):

Debes aplicar la misma ordenación que ya aplicas en la función `agregar_equipos`.
La diferencia es que en esa función podías usar el nombre de cada columna porque tenías diccionarios en vez de listas.
Por lo tanto aquí necesitarás escribir el índice de los campos en función de los cuales quieres hacer la ordenación.
Después de haber modificado los valores necesarios dentro de la función `modificar_equipo` simplemente escribe la línea:

```py
table._rows.sort(key=lambda x: (x[2], x[3]), reverse=True)
```

Tras esto, tenemos que actualizar la primera columna:

```py
for posicion, row in enumerate(table._rows, 1):
    row[0] = posicion
```

---

Ten en cuenta que si vuelves a llamar a la función `agregar_equipos`, tampoco obtendrás una tabla totalmente ordenada:
sólo estarán ordenados los nuevos equipos que hayas añadido.
Necesitarás aplicar la ordenación a la tabla completa.
Ya que vas a ordenar la tabla completa, no es necesario que ordenes la lista `equipos_nuevos` con las nuevas filas antes de añadirlas.